# When i click on delete button of row in listview that row has to deleted and update listview in android

Tags: android, listview, parse-platform, delete-row

I have one list view. In this list view i use custom adpter and take data from the parse.com site.
In my Row it contain 
 1. name of the player textbox. 
 2. score of the player textbox.
 3. Birthday of the player.
 4. Button to delete the data of the that player.
Now i want to delete of player data from parse site.
i am successful in deleting data from the parse site but enable to reflect updated data in that activity.
I have to go in other activity and than i return to this activity it show updated data.
But i want to update that listview instantly when i click on button. I am using Custom adpter for view the list view. If you want code than send me email id i send you code. It is very appreciated.

Comment: Are you pulling new data every time you go to activity? Make sure it is not stored, and post your code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the data in your adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter.

Comment: Where i have to add this notifyDatasetChanged()

Comment: @Bhaumik you have to call that method on the adapter. Do it just after whatever code modifies the data of the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

It'd hard to give advice without code but here is approximate solution:
Try to delete item from your adapters model and then call `notifyDataSetChanged().` For example in your delete button listener do this:

```
mData.remove(position); // position to remove
```

Then delete item from parse store, and in callback done() method call  `notifyDataSetChanged().`

Answer (score 0):

Try on this way to its completed work.

When you get parse get call back if yes then your custom adapter is `notifyDataSetChanged();` and also remove your array index position 
notifiyDataSetChnaged to refresh your adapter.